# YouTube Javascript API: load doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have an implementation of the YouTube Javscript API that works perfectly fine in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Yes, I'm doing this on a webserver ;)

On document ready, I call my function showVideo();

This is all the relevant code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>    

<div id="ytplayer" class="youtubepromovideo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
function showVideo(){
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer", "ytplayer", "400", "400", "8", null, null, params);
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    console.log("player ready: "+playerId);
    loadNewVideo();
}

function loadNewVideo() {
    var id = 'jc8n44ddy9A';
    var startSeconds = 0;
    console.log("loading video");
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(id, startSeconds);
}
</script>
```

In all browsers the player shows, but in Firefox the video doesn't load. My log shows the "loading video" message on firefox, but nothing else happens after that. Not even an error. If I try to call `ytplayer.loadVideoById('jc8n44ddy9A', 0);` manually after everything is loaded, I get the error `ReferenceError: ytplayer is not defined`.

I realize that ytplayer isn't explicitly defined as a variable by me, but my guess(?) is that the YouTube API does that because it works in the other browsers. Also if I defined just `var ytplayer` globally somewhere it doesn't fix it.

Any advise is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the other browsers get the `ytplayer` reference from, but you should have it defined globally (for the example you've given, anyway) and add the reference to it in `onYouTubePlayerReady`:

`ytplayer = document.getElementById( playerId );`

You would likely be better off using the [iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) player, for support in browsers without Flash, too.  I believe it can be loaded without controls using the ["controls" parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#controls).